# VS Code w/ PHP > Go to Declaration

Tags: php, ide, visual-studio-code, intelephense

**config.php**

```
class one {
    function __construct(){
        echo "hello from class one.";
    }
}

require_once("class.php"); $two = new two();
```

**class.php**

```
class two {
    function sayHello(){
        echo "hello from class two";
    }
}
```

**index.php**

```
require_once("config.php");
$one = new one();
$two->sayHello();
```

---

Using VS Code (win64) (with or without the Intelephense Extension) with only **index.php** open in the editor, I should be able to ctrl-click both "one()" and "sayHello()" to open the related files to the class declarations. I'm noticing that:

1. often there is no indication of a hyperlink
2. if there is, it doesn't link anywhere
3. on rare occasion one (or rarer both) will link properly

Is there a setting or a methodology to improve this performance, making the hyperlinking work consistently?

Comment: Try it with PHP Intelephense, and you'll see the above fails -- hence the post to SO.